# Por que campo timestamp no banco de dados firebird é mostrado com valor diferente numa aplicação Ruby on Rails?

Tags: delphi, ruby-on-rails, firebird, timestamp, firebird-2.5

Tenho um banco de dados `Firebird 2.5` legado. Acesso ele via `IBExpert 2016.9.4.1` Esse banco faz parte de um sistema de gerenciamento de solicitações que está sendo migrado de uma aplicação `Delphi 10.1 Update 2` para uma aplicação `Ruby(2.3.3) on Rails(4.2.7.1)`.

Notei que os campos do tipo `TIMESTAMP` estão apresentando divergência entre o que está no banco e o que é mostrado na aplicação `RoR`. Exemplo:

```
 - IBExpert mostra:      30.12.1899 15:10
 - Ruby on Rails mostra: 30.12.1899 15:03
```

Alguém sabe por que isso acontece e como solucionar?

Comment: Qual o valor numérico da data armazenada no banco?

Comment: Não consigo acessar o valor numérico. Pelo IBExpert, ele gera um erro de overflow quando tento dar um CAST.

Comment: Sera que não tem algo relacionado ao formato Unix Timestamp ?

Comment: Possível. Mas como solucionar isso sem alterar os dados do banco?

Comment: Eu alterei o tipo da coluna pra `TIME` ao inves de `TIMESTAMP` e resolveu o problema. Acredito que foi um erro de modelagem do banco.